# Does the indefinite pronoun/determiner "quă" only exist as an enclitic?

Tags: syntax, pronouns, conjunctive, word-usage, enclitic

I recently learned that there is an indefinite determiner and pronoun *quă* used in the feminine nominative singular and neuter nominative/accusative plural with the sense "any(one)" (corresponding to masculine singular indefinite *quis*). If *quă* is an independent word, it would be remarkable in consisting of [a single light syllable, a shape that apparently is shared with no other Latin word](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9021).

But in fact, the occurrence of *quis* and *quă* is restricted in certain suggestive ways (in contrast to *aliquis* etc.), which causes some sources to describe them as **enclitic**: that is, dependent in some way on the preceding word. (Latin has other enclitics, such as *-ne, -que, -ve,* which however have fairly distinct syntactic functions from *quis/quă*.)

A related previous question by Sebastian Koppehel asked about the distribution of *quis*: [When is quis used instead of aliquis?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14353/when-is-quis-used-instead-of-aliquis) In agreement with the summary in that question, *[An Introductory Latin Book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introductory_Latin_Book/E4z_DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22quis%22+%22qua%22+%22quae%22+feminine+neuter+plural&pg=PA46&printsec=frontcover)*, by Albert Harkness (1869), says that *quă* tends to be found specifically "after *si, nisi, ne,* and *num*", although *quae* is also a possibilty in this context (page 46).

[Kennedy 1876](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Public_School_Latin_Grammar_for_the/Kqk0ZHA3iRUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22qua%22+enclitic+%22siqua%22&pg=PA289&printsec=frontcover) says

> The Indefinite pronouns quis, qui, being Enclitic, cannot begin a sentence. They usually follow some particle (si, nisi, ne, an, num, ut, &c.) or a Relative. [...] So numquis, ecquis, etc.

I also found *quă* described (in French) as an enclitic on [this web page](https://www.prima-elementa.fr/chap16.html).

Likewise, [Zumpt 1845](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Grammar_of_the_Latin_Language/RmgPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22si%22+%22nisi%22+%22ne%22+%22num%22+%22qua%22&pg=PA110&printsec=frontcover) says

> [The short form of the indefinite pronoun] is used, in good prose, only after the conjunctions *si, nisi, ne, num,* and after relatives, such as *quo, quanto,* and *quum.* [...] **Some consider the combination of this indefinite *quis* or *qui* with the conjunctions *si, ne, num,* and with the interrogative syllable *en* (*ec*) as peculiar and distinct words**, as *siquis* or *siqui,* *numquis* or *numqui,* **although properly speaking, *ecquis* or *ecqui* alone can be regarded as one word,** for *en* by itself has no meaning.

(A Grammar of the Latin Language, page 110, $136)

Zumpt says that in some cases, one or more words intervene between the conjunction and the short indefinite pronoun, but none of the examples uses *quă.*

"Indefinite Quis in Horace," by Roy C. Flickinger (1929), mentions a number of other cases with intervening words; but again, none with *quă* that I could see (page 121). Flickinger takes issue with the way that grammars describe the distribution of indefinite *quis,* saying

> Only two [of the grammars discussed by Flickinger] state that **indefinite *quis* may be used without any introductory word whatsoever**, though another implies it by citing an instance. Of course, **this usage is not uncommon in Latin literature.** It occurs in Horace certainly at *Serm.* I, 3, 63, and probably at *Serm.* I, 4, 80. In the former passage, however, the clause in which *quis* stands is conditional in force, even though *si* is not expressed.

(page 120)

Here is Serm. I, 3, 63-64, with its use of *quis* to mean "anyone":

> simplicior **quis** et est, qualem me saepe libenter /
> obtulerim tibi, Maecenas, ut forte legentem [...]

I'd like to know whether there are any examples of the specific form *quă* being used when it is not directly after *si, nisi, ne, num,* or a relative word.

Comment: I think we should examine the relevant entry in the OLD at first. It says "**quis**2 **qua** or **quae**, **quid** *indef. pron. (adj.)* [unaccented form of QVIS1 ...]" and the examples under **3** (in a main sentence, in generalizations) Whoever or whatever you choose, anyone, anything and **4** (as adj.) Any (nom. sg. m. and neut. only). Then we could look it up in Pinkster 2015 (p. 1164), 11.149 The indefinite pronoun *quis*, who says "It is rare in main clauses [...], but very common in conditional and other subordinate clauses [...]. It does not occur in first position in its clause."

Comment: also see Bertocchi et al. 2010 (pp. 31-32) https://www.degruyter.com/view/book/9783110215465/10.1515/9783110215465.19.xml etc.